# Is it possible to interrogate a suspect a second time?

Tags: la-noire

I went and interrogated one of my suspects before having all of the facts available to me, so missed out on a couple of questions that may or may not crack this case wide open.

In this instance, I'm on the White Shoe Slaying case and the person I am wanting to re-interrogate is James Jessop. During my first interrogation, I returned straight to Central before following up on the Yellow Taxi lead, which reduced the number of questions that I could ask him and means I possibly missed some important information.

After finding the Yellow Taxi, I went back to the holding cells but he won't talk to me.

Is it possible to interrogate a suspect a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the suspect and the plot. [You can't re-ask the same question again](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115457/1719), but if you don't ask all the questions, you can sometimes leave and come back to the same suspect to finish the interrogation. This will depend on the specific person and the specific case. Unfortunately, there's not really a general rule on whether this will be possible or not. It's usually a good idea to finish interrogating someone once you start.

Additionally, you will sometimes interrogate the same person multiple times through the course of a single case, after you find new evidence or new events transpire. I don't think this is what you're going for, though.

Comment: In this instance, the first time around the sailor was in the interrogation room, the second time around he was in a holding cell and would refuse to talk to me, I didn't seem to have the option of starting a second interrogation...