# How can I re-ask a question I got wrong?

Tags: la-noire

LA Noire features a system where you interrogate suspects by asking them questions, and then either accepting what they say as truth, doubting them, or accusing them of lieing (which requires proof to back up your accusation).

After each question has been asked, the question is crossed off in your notebook with either a tick (correct) or a cross (incorrect) next to it;

[image]

Once you have asked a question, is it possible to re-ask it if you get it wrong? Are your choices in LA Noire final?

Comment: I tended to take a guess at the proper response to the question, and then check the answer with a wiki before confirming.  That way I didn't end up having to reload every time I made a mistake, but I still got a chance to use my personal intuition.

Comment: @agent86 the game already plays itself for the most part, are you telling me that for the parts of it I actually have control over I should refer to a guide? :(

Comment: @kalina, either that or get used to not solving the cases "ideally" or get used to the loading screens.

Comment: It's really part of the game to get it wrong. it defeats the purpose of the game if you can go back to try every response/reaction just to see what each one does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of loading an old save, you can't. Generally, getting one question wrong isn't enough to ruin your chances at a case. The case will still come to a close with some kind of resolution, based on how well you do during interrogations.

In some specific interrogations, if you do poorly enough, you will actually fail and be given the option to start the whole interrogation fresh. These tend to be later in the game and have to go a certain way for plot reasons.